# How to use conditional dropdown in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add two dropdowns.

1. Genre
2. Books

The Books dropdown would be dependent on value selected in Genre dropdown.
I am using react-select library.
With my failed efforts I was able to do this. Dependent dropdown does get filtered, but no value is selected in the select bar.
This is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

class Condiontaldropdown extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: {},
      selectedOption2: {},
    };
  }

  handleChange1 = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
  };

  handleChange2 = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption2: selectedOption });
  };

  render() {
    const Genres = [
      { value: "Fiction", label: "Fiction" },
      { value: "Murder", label: "Murder" },
      { value: "Thriller", label: "Thriller" },
    ];

    const Books = [
      { value: "GOT", label: "GOT", link: "Fiction" },
      { value: "LOTR", label: "LOTR", link: "Fiction" },
      { value: "Angel And Demons", label: "Angel And Demons", link: "Murder" },
      { value: "Dragon", label: "Dragon", link: "Thriller" },
      { value: "Tattoo", label: "Tattoo", link: "Thriller" },
    ];

    const filteredOptions = Books.filter(
      (o) => o.link === this.state.selectedOption.value
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Select your favourite Genre</p>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selectedOption.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange1}
          options={Genres}
        ></Select>
        <p>Select your favourite Book from that genre</p>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selectedOption2.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange2}
          options={filteredOptions}
        ></Select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Condiontaldropdown;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `.value` to the value props of Select but it is not correct.
Please check the following code.

```
 return (
      <div>
        <p> Select your favourite Genre</p>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange1}
          options={Genres}
        ></Select>
        <p>Select your favourite Book from that genre</p>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selectedOption2}
          onChange={this.handleChange2}
          options={filteredOptions}
        ></Select>
      </div>
    );
```